# HttpURLConnection returns error code 500 intermittently

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-9.0-pie, httpsurlconnection, x-www-form-urlencoded

The following URLConnection Post task works well in Android 8, but works intermittently in Android 9. 
For example, it returns Error Code 500 on the first two calls, then on the 3rd call, it returns good Code 200 with a token parameter from a backend response. Other times it works at the first attempt right after compiling and relaunching my app in an Android 9 emulator, works well during a few more calls and then starts returning the flawed error Code 500. 
You get the feel... reliability is around 50/50 random.
I don't think is the Emulator, because a colleague tested the Apk on a physical Android 9 Pie device, and the same behavior happens.
I also believe that my input parameter string is correct because authentication works at least some times, so the error must be on some implementation on my code.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
LoginPIEAsync lp = new LoginPIEAsync(context, params, targetURL, jParams); //L391
lp.execute();



public static class LoginPIEAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        Context context;
        String dataString;
        byte[] bodyData;
        URL url = null;    
        String user, pwd, details, packagename;

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) //Constructor
        public LoginPIEAsync(Context ctx, String params, URL url, JSONObject j) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            this.context = ctx;
            this.bodyData = params.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8);
            this.dataString = params;
            this.url = url;
            loge("ASYNC URL: " + this.url.toString());
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response;
            InputStream stream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8;q=1;ISO-8859-1");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(this.bodyData.length));
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", HTTP.UTF_8);
                //urlConnection.setUseCaches (false);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(19000);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(19000);
                //urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                String baseAuthStr = ANDROID_CONSUMER_KEY + ":" + ANDROID_CONSUMER_SECRET;
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + baseAuthStr);

                OutputStream out = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                out.write(bodyData);
                out.flush ();
                out.close();
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream;
                int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)  {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                }
                else  {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                }

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String result = "";
                String inputLine;

                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    loge("inputSTREAM: " + inputLine);
                    result+=inputLine;
                }
                reader.close();

                loge("PIE CONNECTION, getResponseCode: "+String.valueOf(status));
                loge("PIE CONNECTION, result: "+result);
                return result;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                loge("IOException: "+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    loge("DISCONNECTING.....");
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(25000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                loge("Result, SLEEP ERROR");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result==null){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Token Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Token: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            loge("ASYNC onPostExecute: "+result);
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try sending the request through POSTMAN or Insomnia or any REST API GUI Clients and record the resutls to test the stability.

Just to make sure if the problem wasn't in the actual API itself.

Comment: @UdayaPrakash Yes, running a Curl command on Terminal with the same parameter String worked. I believe I may have an encoding or buffer read problem: curl -XPOST --data "email=delete%40me.com&password=deleteme1&device_details=....." https://portal.myportal.com/m/client/login --verbose

Comment: That is strange. Especially the 50 50 reliability part is strange :(